# Kubernetes pod to pod cluster Network Policy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Using k8s network policy or calico, can I only use these tools for pod to pod cluster network policies.
I already have network rules for external cluster policies.

For example if I apply this calico rule:

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-ingress-from-b
  namespace: app
spec:
  selector: app == 'a'
  ingress:
  - action: Allow
    protocol: TCP
    source:
      selector: app == 'b'
    destination:
      ports:
        - 80
```

In this example I allow traffic coming from app B to app A.
But this will disallow every other ingress traffic going to A.
Would it be possible to only apply this rule from pod to pod ?

Comment: Google East-West traffic. North-South is called from outside-inside cluster, and east-west is intra cluster

Comment: @carlosGarcia sorry if my question was not clear I've updated it.

Answer (score 2):

You should read [The NetworkPolicy resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#networkpolicy-resource), it provides an example NetworkPolicy with `Ingress` and `Egress`.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: db
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 172.17.0.0/16
        except:
        - 172.17.1.0/24
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          project: myproject
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          role: frontend
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.0.0.0/24
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5978
```

The explanation is as following:

> 1. isolates “role=db” pods in the “default” namespace for both ingress and egress traffic (if they weren’t already isolated)
> 2. (Ingress rules) allows connections to all pods in the “default” namespace with the label “role=db” on TCP port 6379 from:
>
>    - any pod in the “default” namespace with the label “role=frontend”
>    - any pod in a namespace with the label “project=myproject”
>    - IP addresses in the ranges 172.17.0.0–172.17.0.255 and 172.17.2.0–172.17.255.255 (ie, all of 172.17.0.0/16 except 172.17.1.0/24)
> 3. (Egress rules) allows connections from any pod in the “default” namespace with the label “role=db” to CIDR 10.0.0.0/24 on TCP port 5978
>
> See the  [Declare Network Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/declare-network-policy/)  walkthrough for further examples.

So if you use a `podSelector`, you will be able to select pods for this Network Policy to apply to.